# Is it possible to pass a variable column name into an ORACLE update statement without dynamic sql

Tags: oracle

```
UPDATE P_ATTR 
    SET XC=ATTR_VAL, 
        SYS_MODIFIED_BY =UPPER(TRIM(USER_ID)), 
        SYS_MODIFIED_DATE =SYSDATE 
WHERE ID_1 IN (SELECT ID_1 
               FROM EMP_MSTR 
               WHERE UPPER(x_SQL)= UPPER(LOC) 
                AND UPPER(LOC_CD)=UPPER('IND'));
```

Getting error message:

> PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "XC": invalid identifier

Comment: No, it is not possible to pass a variable column (or table,or any other object) name without using dynamic sql.  And the fact that you would need to pass dynamic object names raises red flags about your design.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible without dynamic SQL.  You can, however, write a static update statement to interpret the value of a variable and update the correct column.  Like so:

(Assuming "XC" is a PL/SQL variable.  If you are not in PL/SQL, you will need a bind variable, so replace each occurrence of "XC" with ":XC".  Same deal with "ATTR_VAL".)

```
UPDATE P_ATTR 
  SET 
  COLUMN_1 = DECODE(XC,'COLUMN_1',ATTR_VAL,COLUMN_1), 
  COLUMN_2 = DECODE(XC,'COLUMN_2',ATTR_VAL,COLUMN_2), 
  COLUMN_3 = DECODE(XC,'COLUMN_3',ATTR_VAL,COLUMN_3), 
  COLUMN_4 = DECODE(XC,'COLUMN_4',ATTR_VAL,COLUMN_4), 
  ...
  SYS_MODIFIED_BY =UPPER(TRIM(USER_ID)), 
  SYS_MODIFIED_DATE =SYSDATE 
WHERE ID_1 IN( SELECT ID_1 
               FROM   EMP_MSTR 
               WHERE  UPPER(x_SQL)= UPPER(LOC) 
               AND    UPPER(LOC_CD)=UPPER('IND'));
```